# take data from adobe analytics to databricks using api

Tags: oracle, pyspark, adobe, databricks, adobe-analytics

I am trying to connect my databricks cluster to adobe analytics as I dont want to create a csv file and then read it via ftp.

Please help me in implementing how to do that via api as I dont know much about this.

I would really be very grateful to you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull that using API

try and refer the documentation [here](https://www.analyticsintuition.com/blog/getting-started-with-the-adobe-analytics-api-in-python/)

Comment: thanks for this but I need it for version 2 as this is for version 1.4

Comment: See here https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis

Comment: thanks again but i seen this as well as their youtube channel but couldnt get much out of it might be due to my being new to this